# React-Apollo - unclear usage of readQuery/writeQuery in mutation's update function

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm not clear at all about how readQuery and writeQuery work in the context of the  update function passed to a mutation function in react-apollo.
It seems that readQuery returns a reference to the cache, mutating the returned object directly triggers a rerender across my components with the relevant changes, why then do I need to call writeQuery?

Example directly from the docs (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui.html) of an update function passed into mutate :

```
update: (proxy, { data: { submitComment } }) => {
          // Read the data from our cache for this query.
          const data = proxy.readQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery });
          // Add our comment from the mutation to the end.
          data.comments.push(submitComment);
          // Write our data back to the cache.
          proxy.writeQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery, data });
        }
```

now if I comment out the last line :

```
update: (proxy, { data: { submitComment } }) => {
          // Read the data from our cache for this query.
          const data = proxy.readQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery });
          // Add our comment from the mutation to the end.
          data.comments.push(submitComment);
          // Write our data back to the cache.
          // proxy.writeQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery, data });
        }
```

My component and UI would change as soon as the data returned from proxy.readQuery is mutated. What added benefit is there to calling proxy.writeQuery?
Initially I thought proxy.writeQuery would be necessary to notify React of the changes and trigger a re-render to my components, but evidently this is not the case.

Comment: Did you figure it out ?